# ABCChrome117.exe - The program can't start because api-ms-win-core-libraryloader-l1-2-1.dll is missing from your computer

Tags: .net, dll, windows-server-2012-r2, windows-server, abcpdf

I am upgrading my ABCPDF to 13 with a new Chrome Engine.  However I keep getting this error below.  ABCPDF works fine with Gecko and MSHTML.  I am kinda at a lost as this works on my local computer just not on Server 2012 R2 64 bit right now.

```
Application popup: ABCChrome117.exe - System Error : The program can't start because api-ms-win-core-libraryloader-l1-2-1.dll is missing from your computer. Try reinstalling the program to fix this problem.
```